# What term should I use for removing characters from user input (Bank ATM consoles)?

Tags: usability, gui-design, terminology, keypad

We are developing the UI for a banking ATM console where many of our customers are not aware of computers common GUI terminology.

So what term should I use for removing entered characters if someone enters a wrong character and wants to remove it.

We are currently using "Correction". Should I use "Clear", "Cancel", or "Reset"?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the question. Am I right in believing that you've some kind of text field with a 'clear' button, and you want to know what label to give it?

Comment: yes, but its like atm machine

Comment: We are building GUI for ATM Machine.

Comment: edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ATM keypads in the UK seem to work the same way with 3 action buttons:

Cancel / Clear / Enter

- Cancel - Cancels the transaction
- Clear - Clears the number (say a PIN number) entered
- Enter - Submits the information

The answer to your question would therefore be 'clear'

**However:** I'd be very wary of generalising from the way its done in one country to assuming this is the same in all countries (without further research to check whether this is a global standard)

Comment: In our country some of the ATM machine use clear while other use correction.

Answer (score 3):

What term you use depends on what you are describing.

Clear = when you have a field or text area in which you want to clear all the content.

Reset = when you have a default setting or settings and text and would like to return it to its default state.

Cancel = when you have made changes to settings or data and you want to cancel or stop those changes without saving them.

I suspect from your question that you are talking about single characters.  If that is the case, you should use "delete" or "backspace" to describe them.  However if the people that you're dealing with have very little computer experience, it may be more useful to use a symbol for this.  Something like the icon below.

[image]

Whatever term you use, don't use "correctness" as language wise it makes very little sense.

Comment: yes, thank you. but we are building ATM GUI.

Comment: In that case, just use what all other ATMs that I've seen use.  "Correction" which basically acts the same way as "clear"

Comment: I am using Correction too, but that was my typo mistake.